# How do I format my custom html so wpautop won't try to reformat it?

Tags: wp-autop

I've got a desktop app that generates html for my customers to paste into their WP pages/posts. Nothing fancy just some image tags, hyperlinks and simple inline css.

How do I preformat that code so wpautop won't try to re-format? What triggers that function to add br and p tags? Are there any other tags it will insert?

Answer (score 0):

The function that does what I think you are referring to is [`wpautop()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop), probably the most complained about function is all of WordPress-dom. It is a filter on the `the_content` hook [among others](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php). You can remove that with:

```
remove_filter('the_content','wpautop');
```

I would suggest that you spend some time looking through the [many related questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=wpautop) to see what you are getting yourself into.